# Problem with Form/Window Caption on HIGH DPI, Delphi 10.3 and VCLStyles SKIN

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles

New Delphi 10.3 project
Applicaton - Manifest - Enable Runtime Themes, DPI Awareness Per Monitor v2 (so default)

```
Project uses
Vcl.Styles,
Vcl.Styles.Hooks,
Vcl.Styles.Utils.Forms,
Vcl.Styles.Utils.StdCtrls,
Vcl.Styles.Utils.ComCtrls,
Vcl.Styles.Utils.ScreenTips,
Vcl.Styles.Utils.SysControls,
Vcl.Styles.Utils.SysStyleHook,
Vcl.Styles.Utils.Shadow,
Vcl.Styles.FormStyleHooks
```

MainForm has

```
procedure TForm24.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
      var Style    : TStyleManager.TStyleServicesHandle;
begin
  self.font := screen.iconfont;
  self.PixelsPerInch := screen.PixelsPerInch;
  style:=TStyleManager.LoadFromFile(extractfilepath(paramstr(0))+'Dark Outlet Media.vsf');
  tstylemanager.SetStyle(style);
end;
```

First if we run this app on HIGH DPI we get:

[Look at the caption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3IZT.png)

Look at the caption - form caption is not visible at all - font size is too big and overloads caption area.

If we add following code at the FormCreate then the main app and all other captions look weard

```
StyleDPIAwareness := TStyleDPIAwareness.Create(Self);
StyleDPIAwareness.Parent := Self;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN9g5.png)

TitleBar on Form Caption heigth is too big, and font is fisible, but I think too big too.

First question is I couldnt find a way to set window/form/caption font size, font weight and even font family name. We can set default font for Form, for all controls on form, but not form caption.

Also is there a way to decrease increasing height of the form caption in high dpi - so it is not as big as it is now.

This works fine in Delphi 10.2 with VCLStyles. Doesnt work with Delphi 10.3 with or without VCLStyles.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue?